# PHP Mysql count distinct reasons given where reason value in another table

Tags: php, mysql, count, distinct

I want to create a statistics page where i can count the number of reasons given in a table ...The reasons are created dynamically and stored in another table.

Table1 contains all the reasons which populate a drop down box...
Table2 contains the entries given by the user one of the columns is the reason value.

I would like to count the amount of times each reason appears .

Thankyou for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like simply group statement:

```
select
    reason.name reason,
    count(*) count
from entry, reason
where
    entry.reason = reason.id and
    entry.time > now() - interval 7 day -- you probably need some filter
group by reason.id
```

Comment: Thankyou! That worked great...
What i would like is to implement this between two dates.... unfortunately the data im working with has string dates (in dd/mm/yyyy format) I would like the above count process to include -7 (or +7 days from current date)

Comment: this is what i have got so far-

`$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(id) AS value,signoutreason,signoutdate FROM pupils WHERE signoutdate BETWEEN '".date('d/m/Y')."' AND '".date('d/m/Y', strtotime('-7 days'))."' GROUP BY signoutreason");`

Comment: To all trying to do a between comparison with two date strings...don't.
It's so much easier to convert the data to date format in the database first!